# Add validation to __call__ methods in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, design-patterns, composition

I have a large hierarchy of classes stemming from `Function` class (for example `SineFunction` would be a child), and all of them implement the `__call__` method, as well as other methods (for example derivation or more specialized numerical methods).

What is the cleanest way of adding common logic to each of these `__call__` methods based on the type of the input? Formally, I'd like to have something like

```
def __call__(self,x):
    if isinstance(x,Distribution):
        return FunctionDistribution(x,self)
    else:
        # Go back to previous logic
```

for each child class of `Function`. I could add `super()` at each implementation of `__call__` but that would be painful. Anything easier to achieve this?

Comment: Is `FunctionDistribution` the same in every version? Or will it vary across different `__call__` methods? Is there always one argument?

Comment: Not sure if it applies to your case, but you might want to look at [single dispatch generic functions (introduced in 3.4)](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.4.html#whatsnew-singledispatch), where you can define a global function with a generic implementation, plus specializations for specific types. It may or may not mesh well with your current "functor" based design, but I figure it's work checking.

Answer (score 3):

How about something like this?

```
class BaseFunction(object):
    def __call__(self, x):
        if isinstance(x, BaseFunction):
            return self._call(x)
        else:
            print("Fallback logic goes here")

    def _call(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

class ChildFunction(BaseFunction):
    def _call(self, x):
        print("Child function executed on x")
```

The child classes each define `_call`, and the fallback logic resides in the parent class.

An example:

```
>>> a = BaseFunction()
>>> b = ChildFunction()
>>> c = 3
>>> b(a)
Child function executed on x
>>> b(c)
Fallback logic goes here
```

**Editorializing:**

As an aside, I don't know much about your particular use case, but my understanding is that `isinstance` is very often not the ideal choice, and it's better to do some sort of [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). In which case, you'd probably want to replace the `if(isinstance(...` statement with a `try`/`except` block where you just use the interface *as if* `x` implements the `BaseFunction` interface.

Comment: Yeah it could do, however it implies renaming `__call__` to `_call` for each implementation, which is annoying.

Comment: @Literal I suppose you're actually physically renaming `__call__` if you already have an implementation using `__call__`, but in reality what you're doing is implementing an additional method `_call`, and the original `__call__` is inherited from `BaseFunction`, if that's not clear.

Comment: Also, it seems like a pretty simple search-and-replace. Probably better to do it once, now, than to design some weird metaclass that just does something equivalent at runtime.